# read file to few arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm really new in python and I have my first problems. I have 5 files .csv and I would like to read this file to few arrays. So my data see as:

```
data11 data12 ... data1n 
data21 data22 ... data2n 
         ....
datan1 datan2 ... datann
```

I want to have 3 arrays. First with column1, second with column2 and third with everything else. i try do it and I wrote this:

```
odczyt.append(csv.reader(open('1.csv'),delimiter=','))
odczyt.append(csv.reader(open('2.csv'),delimiter=','))
odczyt.append(csv.reader(open('3.csv'),delimiter=','))
odczyt.append(csv.reader(open('4.csv'),delimiter=','))
odczyt.append(csv.reader(open('5.csv'),delimiter=','))

for plik in odczyt:
    tab.append(map(int, wiersz[0]) for wiersz in plik)
    tab1.append(map(int, wiersz[1]) for wiersz in plik)
    tab2.append(map(float,wiersz[2:]) for wiersz in plik)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? what does it do, what is the issue with it?

Comment: When i try print something i get:
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x055EE198>

Comment: copy and paste the whole error please. That is not an error, thats a generator expr object.

Comment: `(map(int, wiersz[0]) for wiersz in plik)` creates a generator object.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: There is any error, but I don't have any idea what do with this generator.

Comment: Use `extend` instead of `append`.

Comment: Ok, I try use this code without generator and files are reading by column, no by row...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem but now I have other. When I try convert string -> int, instead of one int, I get array of int. For example:
should be 12, is [1,2].
This is my code:

```
    for i in range(5):
      with open("%d.csv" %i, "r") as odczyt[i]:
        wiersze[i] = odczyt[i].readlines()
        for wiersz in wiersze[i]:
            tokers = wiersz.split(',')
            tab[i].append(map(int, tokers[0]))
            tab1[i].append(map(int, tokers[1]))
            tab2[i].append(map(float, tokers[2:]))
```

With tab2 everything is ok, but tab and tab1 work as I wrote on the top.

Answer (score 0):

The very basic solution would be to read file line-by-line and parse them. Pleas efind the example below:

```
     arr1 = []
     arr2 = []
     arr3 = []

     with open ('my_file.csv') as infile:
         ss = infile.readlines()
     for line in ss:
         entries = line.split(",")
         arr1.append(entries[0])
         arr2.append(entries[1])
         arr3.append(",".join(entries[2:]))
```

Regarding the second question - map works on iterables, but you give it a string instead. It has nothing to do but to convert it to an object it can iterate through. Array of chars in this case. Then , it applies the int convertion to every char and gives you the result. The corerct code for your tab1 and tab0 would be:

```
         tab.append(int(wiersz[0]) for wiersz in plik)
         tab1.append(int(wiersz[1]) for wiersz in plik)
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this solution few moments before you wrote it ;)